# AngularJS- How to populate second select on selection of option from first select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. In my application i have two `<select>`. The second select has to be dependent on the value selected from first select selected.
Following is my controller data:

```
$scope.types=[{type:"Cars"},{type:"Bykes"}];

$scope.Cars= [{"id":1,"CarName":"Hundai"},{"id":2,"CarName":"Maruti"},{"id":3,"CarName":"Toyoto",}];

$scope.Bykes= [{"id":10,"BykeName":"Honda"},{"id":8,"BykeName":"Bajaj"},{"id":9,"BykeName":"TVS"}];
```

Following is My HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 top10">
    <select class="form-control select1" ng-model="selectedType" ng-init="selectedType='Cars'">
        <option ng-repeat="type in types">{{type.type}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <select ng-model="vehicle"  class="form-control select2"   >
        <option ng-repeat="car in Cars" value="{{car}}">{{car.CarName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Actually My Cars and Bykes data comes from database.

Now as if i select cars from first select , accordingly only cars should be displayed in the second select and if i select Bykes only Bykes should be displayed in second select.

Please help me on this.Thanx in advance.

Comment: Put the logic in the controller, a function to determine the contents of the cascaded list. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: You just need to know about ng-if and ng-show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you could do, without modifying many things in your code.

you could make use of ng-if to check on the selected vehicle type and display the corresponding dropdown accordingly.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.types = [{
      type: "Cars"
    }, {
      type: "Bykes"
    }];

    $scope.Cars = [{
      "id": 1,
      "CarName": "Hundai"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "CarName": "Maruti"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "CarName": "Toyoto",
    }];

    $scope.Bykes = [{
      "id": 10,
      "BykeName": "Honda"
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "BykeName": "Bajaj"
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "BykeName": "TVS"
    }];

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController as vm">
    <div class="col-lg-2 top10">
      <select class="form-control select1" ng-model="vm.selectedType" ng-init="vm.selectedType='Cars'">
        <option ng-repeat="type in types">{{type.type}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3" ng-if="vm.selectedType=='Cars'">
      <select ng-model="vehicle" class="form-control select2">
        <option ng-repeat="car in Cars" value="{{car}}">{{car.CarName}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" ng-if="vm.selectedType=='Bykes'">
      <select ng-model="vehicle" class="form-control select2">
        <option ng-repeat="byke in Bykes" value="{{byke}}">{{byke.BykeName}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <span>
    </span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would have upvoted, but the view really does not need any conditionals. Simply iterate through a single result set, based on type.

Comment: I thought of the same way. But the data is of different format, BykeName vs CarName

Comment: The point being you are putting logic in the view, instead of letting the controller handle the logic

Comment: If the data structure for Cars and Bykes is the same, then it would have been a simple flip.

Comment: I m curious to learn , how we can do it. Without changing the data structure and having the logic only in the controller.

Comment: You have a good point, you would have to adjust the model to be more abstract, and map the source data to your generic model

Comment: That would be an ideal solution, As I mentioned thought about. But that requires OP to change things everywhere, as the data is coming from the Database, as per his question.

Comment: Yes, Shreekanth exactly. I found many solutions where field name is same like 'name'. But in my case it was 'carName' and 'bykeName' which  is rigid at database  and we can't change it.

Comment: Anyways, @shreekanth it worked for me . Thankx again.

Answer (score 1):

[Here the answer](http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/TsxTU/14/)

### Here

`populate` second select based on select of option from first select